# Testing the existence of a function (a dynamically referenced function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The below script is trying to test the existence of lets say Utility.Method.PageInit();

the page object comes in dynamically, as does the event parameter, so I don't actually know what they will be, so I need to test the existence of a dynamic function (if you understand me correctly).

```
var key = page.attr('id');
var funcToCall = key + '.Method.' + event;

//check if function exists, if it doesn't return, (guard statement)
if (typeof (eval(funcToCall)) != 'function') { return; }
```

Problem is, the eval is actually calling it, and then its throwing an error "function doesn't exist blahblah".

How can I test the existence of it without getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I've figured it out, didn't realize how easy was, because its a function inside an object, inside an object you need to test from the top level down progressively, so:

```
if (typeof (eval(key)) != 'object' || typeof (eval(key + '.Method')) != 'object' || (typeof (eval(funcToCall)) != 'function')) { return; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that doesn't require `eval` at all could be

```
if (!window[key] || (typeof window[key].Method) != "function") return;
```

This works because what is logically true can be checked for members safely (and returns `undefined` if the member is not present).

It is an error to check `x.Method` when `x` is `null` or `undefined`, but those special values are logically false so the code above never raises an exception.

If the method name is also dynamic you can use the equivalent indexing access approach, still without need of `eval`... for example:

```
m = "Method"
if (!window[key] || (typeof window[key][m]) != "function") return;
```